# Android Buttons look different when added by code

Tags: java, android, layout, android-button, android-styles

I found that a button that is added to a layout by code looks very different than a button defined in xml.
I made a short example.

Here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewCommands"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button in xml"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("button by code");
btn.setBackgroundColor(0xff00e033);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout lo = findViewById(R.id.viewCommands);
lo.addView(btn, lp);
```

And this is what it looks like. Quite different, isn't it?
[image: example image]

I did not add any style to the button in code except background color, so no wonder it's so boring.
But I also didn't add anything in xml and as both buttons land in the same layout. If the layout adds style to elements, what's the difference?

I would appreciate to get some more insight in this.
How can I make the code-added buttons look the same as those coming from xml?

*please see that in contrast to many other questions I found, this question is not about different look on different devices, Android versions, frameworks, resolutions, apps... it's in the very same layout.*

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67197434/programmatically-created-button-doesnt-follow-themes-button-style) could be the reason

Comment: @Zain I guess this is a good kick into the right direction for me. Unfortunately I don't know much about the styles and themes and where they inherit from, and there are a ton of different styles I can chose from when I use the other class mentioned in your link. But I am sure I will find the solution, now as I know about the mechanism that secretly happens here. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this is getting horrible to understand. My app style seems to be inherited from `Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar`. Now what do I have to specify for my button to use this style? I tried everything that came to my mind but nothing makes both buttons look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My app style seems to be inherited from Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar. Now what do I have to specify for my button to use this style?

So, the idea is that the XML abstract `Button` is automatically converted to the appropriate button version that comply with the app theme. That is not the case when it comes to do that programmatically because the exact Java/Kotlin Button class is already specified and imported.

The referenced [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67197784/9851608) is suitable for **Theme.AppCompat** (Material 1) where its Button version is `AppCompatButton`.

Starting from **Material components** (Material 2 library), the Button version is the [`MaterialButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton) which extends from the `AppCompatButton` but has a different/enhanced style.

As you use `Material3` library, then you need to use `MaterialButton` instead of `Button` programmatically:

```
MaterialButton btn = new MaterialButton(this);
...
```

Comment: This is amazingly simple - if only I had known about it. Thank you so much!